# Spherical harmonics visualization as oscillations on sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen, spherical-harmonics

I‘ve watched this [video](https://youtu.be/Ziz7t1HHwBw) where they visualize the spherical harmonics as oscillations. Since the spherical harmonics determine the spatial shape of the orbitals of the hydrogen atom their time evolution (multiplied with the radial solution) is trivial and therefore nothing oscillates. The only way I can imagine that there oscillates something is when they plot only the real part. Because then we get for example:
$$Y_{1}^{-1}(t)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\vartheta\:\mathrm{e^{-i(\varphi+\omega t)}}$$
$$\Re(Y_{1}^{-1}(t))=\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi}}\sin\vartheta\:\mathrm{\cos(i(\varphi+\omega t))}$$
Is this true?
And my second question is why the the only way of rotation the nodal line is right/left and not up/down or would it break the symmetry?

Comment: You are just trying to overcomplicate spherical harmonics. What you should be viewing at is Legendre polynomials, which are by-product of Legendre differential equation. It is just one of many ODE's of second order, nothing very special about it. Just look into simple side and don't look at funny pictures which mean nothing. Real electrons do not "rotate" around nuclei on some "funny looking spherical harmonical surface". It is merely numerical shadow of what's going on.

Comment: They don‘t say that the electrons are rotating around nuclei but they say that where the vibration amplitude on the spherie is large there is also the probability to find an electron big. @sanaris